# unable to obtain topic data error in ibm message hub

Tags: message-hub

suddenly getting error on ibm message hub. "unable to get topic data". Everything was working fine till couple of hours ago.

Checked:
1. Usage. Everything seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

We had to shutdown the topic admin API for about 30 minutes this afternoon. It is now back up and running.